# Notes has Google Notes. But Google has no such service. Where are they stored?

Tags: notes.app, google

If you go to System Preferences -> Internet Accounts and add a Google account, you can see Google has Notes. If you open **Notes** (OS X app), it somehow retrieves the notes I had put long long time ago on a different Mac. So, I am sure those notes are not locally stored. Not only can I see old notes, but I can also add new notes to Google Notes.

Google had Notebook service, but it was discontinued long time ago and existing notes were imported into Google Docs. But I cannot find the notes I see in **Notes** in Google Docs.

So where are the Google Notes stored and **Notes** is getting the notes from? Is it that Google discontinued the web interface of the Notebook service but somehow still provides an interface to Apple especially? Can I access the notes I saved to Google Notes in **Notes** outside the **Notes** application, in a web browser for example?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The notes created in OS X can be found in GMail under the label "*Notes*". If you create a folder with [name] in OS X Notes app, the notes will be synced to Google Inbox unbundled label "*Notes/name*".

Comment: I found it. I wonder why I did not see it before.

Comment: Such a weird idea.

Comment: Google has shut down Inbox, so this is no longer an option.

Comment: @SterlingArcher You can see it in Gmail under Notes label.

Comment: For the account in question, that label was completely empty. I should mention that it was a G Suite account.

Comment: is there a place in Gmail for deleted notes? I by mistake deleted a note from Mac Notes app which was synced to Google account.

Comment: I found the notes in Gmail under the label. Is there a way to update the note outside of OSX?  Maybe I can just email myself the updated doc with the same title etc?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot? I still can not find Notes label.

Answer (score 0):

In you enable the sync, the notes are saved as "*Sent mails*" in Gmail. Sometimes this can be very annoying, since a new sent email is created every time you just modify a previous note. I had enabled once, but now I get rid of this sync option.

Comment: No, I cannot find notes in Drafts. My Gmail Drafts are empty.

Comment: Sorry, try on "sent mails". I have notes there

Comment: No, I cannot see them in Sent either. I put a weird phrase in Notes and searched Gmail, Keep, Google Docs for that phrase, but there was no result.

Answer (score 0):

My Macbook SSD broke down so I went to Gmail and entered label:notes on the search field. I found all my notes intact :)
You can try the same.

Comment: Solid could sync strategy to save data. Well done - not seeing how this adds much over the selected answer, though.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a new folder under Google in the Notes app, otherwise you won't find the bundle or anything in your Google inbox.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little to make it clearer what the solution is.